# Find page address in .NET

Tags: .net, url

Does anyone know how I might programmatically discover the current page's full address.  We share our codebase accross several clients in subdomains and I am trying to discover which client is viewing the page in order to load appropriate CSS, eg. red.website.com; blue.website.com; (I am looking to grab the red or blue, in my code).

Many thanks. Apologies for the poor wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full path should be: [`Request`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx)`.`[`Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx)`.`[`AbsoluteUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri.aspx)?

Once you have a `Uri` (simply `Resuest.Url`), something like:

```
string color = uri.Host.Split('.')[0];
```

Comment: very fast response and dead on.  Thanks so much!

Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split(".")(0) Was the VB 2.0 command I used.